# Using the token_metadata @offchain_view to load tzip-21 compliant metadata

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

Are there any downsides to how I'm declaring the token_metadata in the `@offchain_view` below? Loading the data from storage appears to work as expected when testing it on tzcomet and BCD, though I just want to confirm this approach looks good.

I want to build out the `attributes` JSON array to be compliant with the [tzip-21](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tzip/-/blob/master/proposals/tzip-21/tzip-21.md#attributes-array) interface, but doing the string manipulation for that is going to be a huge pain. Is there a utility I could import for this? Are there any code reference for a tzip-21 token_metadata offchain_view that have the attributes map? Thanks in advance.

```
    @sp.offchain_view(pure = True)
    def token_metadata(self, tok):
         sp.set_type(tok, sp.TNat)

         sp.result(sp.record(token_id=tok, token_info={
            "name": self.data.token_metadata[tok].token_info["name"],
            "symbol": self.data.token_metadata[tok].token_info["symbol"],
            "decimals": self.data.token_metadata[tok].token_info["decimals"],
            "description": Utils.Bytes.of_string("A unique TezosAsset NFT representing someone's purchased asset."),
            "isBooleanAmount": Utils.Bytes.of_string("true"),
            "artifactUri": Utils.Bytes.of_string(string_concat("http://abcd.xyz/asset/", string_of_nat(self.data.arr[tok].x))),
            # TODO: encode x,y under JSON attributes array
            "x": Utils.Bytes.of_string(self.string_of_nat(self.data.arr[tok].x)),
            "y": Utils.Bytes.of_string(self.string_of_nat(self.data.arr[tok].y))
         }))
```

Comment: is the dynamic artifact uri the reason you're wanting to do this? i would love to be able to serve dynamic tzip-21 from a contract, did you manage to get this working correctly? if so can you answer your own question here?

Answer (score 0):

Generally the tzip-21 are implemented as JSON document on ipfs and the CID (the URI of the content on IPFS) are save in the token_info field as a bytes.
Your implementation seems a little bit unusual or better, because is not the most used method, is possible that some wallet or Explorer could not show it correctly, moreover is a lot of field to put into a BigMap and process in a transaction with a poor user Experience, the "best" and cheapest way is to upload the JSON tzip-21 on IPFS and then pass only the response CID to the contract, but is a your Design decision.